# Which star trek series main ship/base/structure had the most events that destroyed it?

Tags: star-trek

It just occurred to me that across the different Star Trek series, there are many instances where the show's main ship or base is destroyed.  For example, in Next Gen, alternate (time looped) Picard ran from his ship while it exploded, or the crew keeps ramming Dr Frasier Crane's ship (presumably because his radio show was drawing attention away from Troi). Which show has the most separate instances of this?

To be clear, anytime a ship was physically replaced (the defiant, for example) would be the end of its run.  The new ship or base would begin as its own string of destructions.

Ships magically becoming two of the same ship,  time travel events, and the ship/base's actual destruction count.  In the situation of exploding over and over again in the same event, count it as one occurance.  As a technicality, if the ship melts instead of explodes, or is somehow destroyed in a non fiery manner, that counts too.  Finally, DS9 and the Defiant qualify as "main" for the purpose of my question.

Comment: So are you only counting time travel paradoxes and space-wibbly-wobbly things where the ship just came back again?

Comment: @Richard Do we count the 1701, and the 1701-A the same ship since they have mostly the same crew?  Heck in terms of movies the 1701 has the most damage done to it, since it took heavy damage in 1 &2, then destroyed in 3.

Comment: @Richard, I think that covers it.  Basically, no cases of enterprise e replacing d, or defiant 2 replacing defiant 1.

Comment: @Cbredlow, please count those separately.

Comment: Wow, I kept thinking that this should be a dupe, but couldn't find it at the time.  Thanks guys!